# Pass data continuosly from class to activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I beginner in android.Goal of my project is to plot graph from continuous data received from Bluetooth which is accelerometer data consist of x,y,z values.Now I want to pass these values to another activity which will plot graph from it.I have taken Blueterm app sourcecode and extended it to extract accel x,y,z values.My question whether intent will do job or I will need to use some other method? 
Below is that thread class which receives data continuously:

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;


    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {

                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                int buflen=buffer.length;
                String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8"); // prints character
                Log.d("Data Transmitted", str);
                int slen=str.length();
                String sl=String.valueOf(slen);
                Log.d("String length",sl);
                int spaceIndex = str.indexOf(" ");
                if (spaceIndex != -1)
                {
                    str = str.substring(0, spaceIndex);
                }
              //  Log.d("Data Edited", str);
                boolean v1=str.contains("a");                   
                boolean v2=str.contains("b");
                boolean v3=str.contains("c");
                boolean v4=str.contains("d");

                int count1 = str.length() - str.replace("a", "").length();
                int count2 = str.length() - str.replace("b", "").length();
                int count3 = str.length() - str.replace("c", "").length();
                int count4 = str.length() - str.replace("d", "").length();
                int count5 = str.length() - str.replace("e", "").length();
                int count6 = str.length() - str.replace("f", "").length();


                if(v1==true && v2==true && v3==true && v4==true && count1==1 && count2==1 && count3==1 && count4==1 && count5==1 && count6==1){
                int v= str.indexOf("a");
                int r= str.indexOf("b");
                int s= str.indexOf("c");
                int k= str.indexOf("d");

               // System.out.println(v);
              //  System.out.println(r);
               // System.out.println(s);
              //  System.out.println(k);
               if(v<r && r<s && s<k){
                String op1=str.substring(str.indexOf("a")+1, str.indexOf("b"));
                double value1 = Double.parseDouble(op1);
                Log.d("Accel-X", op1);
                System.out.print(value1);
                String op2=str.substring(str.indexOf("b")+1, str.indexOf("c"));
                double value2 = Double.parseDouble(op2);
                Log.d("Accel-Y", op2);
                System.out.print(value2);
                String op3=str.substring(str.indexOf("c")+1, str.indexOf("d"));
                double value3 = Double.parseDouble(op3);
                Log.d("Accel-Z", op3);
                System.out.print(value3);
              //  mEmulatorView.write(buffer, bytes);
             //   seriesX.add(new GraphViewData(dataCount, sensorX));

                }
                else{

                //mEmulatorView.write(buffer, bytes);
                }
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                //mHandler.obtainMessage(BlueTerm.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            }} catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have a few options.

Easiest way would be to put your data gathering class in a thread inside your Activity, here you could post directly to the UI.

Second would be to put your data gathering code in an Android Service and bind to the service.  You can create an interface with a callback and return the data to your activity.  This method has lots of interface and binding code.

I would put my data gathering code in a background thread in a Service or IntentService.  Then post the data updates via an [EventBus][1].  Listen for the events in your Activity.  Very clean and easy.